# C++ get a substring from a vector of chars

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I have a vector of chars:

```
std::vector<char> V = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
```

How can I extract a substring from this vector? For example, I want to get an "ABC" value of type `std::string`. What is the most efficient way?

I also would like to avoid copying data as I'm not going to modify the string.

Comment: `std::copy()` maybe??

Comment: `std::string str(V.begin(), V.begin() + 3)`?

Comment: Alternatively, `std::string str(V.data(), 3)`

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` owns the data it holds, so it's not possible to create one without copying the characters. C++17 offers a non-owning [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), which would not create a copy (but due to that you need to ensure lifetime of vector is long enough for the string_view uses).

```
std::string s1 (V.data(), V.data() + 3); //iterator constructor
std::string s2 (V.data(), 3); //pointer + count constructor

std::string_view sv1 (V.data(), V.data() + 3); //iterator constructor
std::string_view sv2 (V.data(), 3); //pointer + count constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<char>` has a member function called `data()` that can return the character buffer (which would be a c-string, had it ended with '\0' - not sure if that change is ok for you). This you don't need to copy.

If you wanted a `std::string`, then a copy is necessary:

```
std::string s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

If all you need is a string-like variable, you can go with c-string or `std::string_view`, latter being a non-owning string.

Comment: How long will the string be? My vector does not have a null terminator

Comment: @Kaiyakha Without a null, you need to resort to the iterator based ctor I think (see above edit).